# Is the following function integrable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $X:\Omega\rightarrow S$ with $S\subset\Bbb R$ is a bounded random variable with the density $p(x)$ and the function $u:S\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a concave, continuous differentiable, monotone function, which is bounded from above but not below. Does it imply that $$E[u(X)]$$ exist? What is the weakest condition on $u$ to make the expectation $E[u(X)]$ exist?

Comment: If $X$ is bounded, then (by continuity) $\lvert u(X)\rvert$ is bounded -- unless I am missing something, you don't need concavity and monotonicity.

Comment: @ClementC. How can I proof it? Suppose X is bounded, there exist $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $c_1\leq X \leq c_2$. As u is continuous, and $c_1,c_2$ defines a compact interval, then u takes maximum and minimum on the interval and is bounded. However, I struggle little bit that $u(c_1)$ and $u(c_2)$ might be not defined.

Comment: Your function $u$ -- what is its domain? I assumed $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: @ClementC. The domain is the image of the $X$.

Comment: I feel we're going in circles. If $X$ takes values in $[a,b]$ and $u$ is defined on $[a,b]$, then you're done. Otherwise, give more details...

Comment: @ClementC. I updated my question, the set $S$ does not necessarily be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest condition guaranteeing the existence of expectation $\mathbb E[u(X)]$ is continuity of $u(x)$ on the closure of $S$. This closure $\bar S$ is a compact, and $u(\bar S)$ is compact too by continuity, and so it is bounded. Then the set $u(S)$ is bounded too as a subset of $u(\bar S)$.

Let us show by example the role of continuity on $\bar S$.

Consider $\Omega=[0,1]$ equipped with Borel sigma-algebra and Lebesgue measure. Let 
$$X(\omega)=\begin{cases}\omega, & \omega\neq 0\cr 1, & \omega = 0\end{cases}$$
Then $X:\Omega \to (0,1]$ is uniformly distributed with density $p(x)=\mathbb 1_{(0,1)}(x)$.

Set $u(x)=-\frac1x$. This function is continuous on $(0,1]$, but not on $[0,1]$. It is also concave and monotone, and bounded from above. And the set $u(X)=(-\infty, -1]$ is not bounded and the expectation does not exist:
$$\mathbb E[|u(X)|]=\int_0^1 \frac1x \,dx=\infty$$

Note also that the existence of expectation depends not only on $u(x)$, but also on a given density. In probability space given above, let $p(x)=2x\mathbb 1_{(0,1)}(x)$ and $u(x)=-\frac1x$. In this case the expectation $\mathbb E[u(X)]$ exists. If we want to guarantee the existence of the expectation regardless of the type of density, we need the boundedness of $u(x)$. You can achieve it either by the requirement of continuity on the closure of $S$, or by requiring directly.